# How in C++ multiple inheritance choose of which base class method will be inherited?

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, ambiguity, virtual-inheritance

Consider following simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        cout<<"A"<<endl;
    }
};

class B: public virtual A {
public:
    virtual void foo(){
        cout<<"B"<<endl;
    }
};

class C : public virtual A {
public:
    virtual void foo(){
        cout<<"C"<<endl;
    }
};

class D : public B, public C {
    public:
        void print(){
            foo();
        }
};

int main () {
    D d;
    d.print();
    return 0;
}
```

This code will not work, because call to foo is ambigous. But question is:

How can I define which methods from which classes should be inherited? And if I have the such opportunity?

Comment: Basically there's one question and one advice:
Q: What's your specific use-case for multiple inheritance ambiguity to occur?
A: Don't use multiple inheritance, since there's almost always a way around, leading to more explicit designs.

Comment: @MABVT Multiple inheritance is extremely useful and alternatives usually add complexity.

Comment: @curiousguy Hm. Multiple inheritance itself might be useful, if you don't have to deal with those ambiguity concerns!
In fact i rarely had use cases for Mult.Inh. with conscious ambiguity being involved before... Oo 

Just being curious: Do you have any specific examples, where OPs situation occurrs and is in fact in a useful context? 

Seems like i can learn something new at this point. ;)

Comment: @MABVT Do you often get ambiguities with MI? When you do, it is a difficult problem?

Comment: It is certainly a dup, but the dupped question mentioned is different.

Comment: @curiousguy Since i hardly use MI, I don't encounter problems. A classic example I found in a book years ago for that situation was:
class Vehicle { virtual void move(); }; class Car : public Vehicle { virtual void move(); }; class Boat : public Vehicle { virtual void move(); }; class AmphibianVehicle : public Car, public Boat { void move(); };

This way I had to distinguish using Car::move();...

Since I became a OOP guy due to work I'd rather declare interfaces and use another approach.

Comment: @MABVT Since `Vehicle` is an interface, you should derive virtually.

Comment: @curiousguy In this case Vehicle is a standalone class not meant to be an interface. The example above is not using any interface (in OOP sense )at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87694/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-mabvt).

Comment: @MABVT No one says, that MI is panacea or it is better than some other solutions.
I like answer on question "Does MI needed?" from this FAQ.
I recommend you to read this section of FAQ
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance

Comment: @RomanTymchyshyn Thanks for the link. Very useful indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disambiguate the call to the function. Take the following example:

```
class A { virtual void foo(); };
class B { virtual void foo(); };
class C : public A ,public B { void foo(); };
```

To call either foo from A, B or even from the child class: C do

```
C *obj = new C;
obj->foo();
obj->A::foo();
obj->B::foo();
```

Source/inspiration: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/multiple_inheritance.html

Comment: So, you suggest me often write function foo in C-class, where make calls to that variant of foo, which I need?

Comment: Yes, you need to override foo() in class C, but it doesn't necessarily need to do anything. Its use is to make an explicit qualification. Tldr, C::foo() can be empty.

Comment: If it can be empty, why even call this function?

Comment: You do not need to call it. It's there just to disambiguate. It can call functions too but not needed.

Comment: What is the specification of `foo()`? If the specification allows an empty body, why do you even need this function?

Comment: Just to make everything clear, in my example, the C::foo() is not needed. But in OP's case (diamond inheritance), if you do not declare C::foo(), you will get an ambiguous inheritance error on compilation (most likely). Try it out yourself.

Comment: I was only interested in next: are there some constructions in language (not workarounds) which allow to choose variant of inherited method.

Thanks for extremly simple and clear answer.